# How to create dynamic classes using PHP and using with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am going to create a PHP snippet or can be considered as WordPress code snippet, and want to create a dynamic css class each time that module loaded on the front end, and that class will be used by jQuery to style my front end.

Here is the scenario:

Let suppose first time module loaded on front end, it should have a class like: `module-front-end-123` and I can use this exact class from jQuery to style its content according to data living inside this module only.

And now suppose another module of same type added now it should generate some class like `module-front-end-124` and I will be using this class from jQuery again to out put its styling as well.

Advantage of this approach will be this, I'll be writing my code snippet only once and when ever module gets loaded I'll be getting its own class and jQuery code will work on this module and for other module style will be working for other module independently.

I can create that class by PHP but don't know how to use that class in jQuery or any thing like that ...

Can anyone guide me please? I just want to write my style only once and each time that will applied to fetched class.

Comment: Just to clarify, you know how to set the class via PHP, but not how to pass it to jQuery?

Comment: Yes you are almost right .... I can create class for each module but don't know how to send that class to jquery and use that class as I needed ...

Comment: Store your class in PHP as a variable and pass that variable to jQuery. Here's an example of how to do that: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/scalar.php

Comment: No, I am not working in PHP based js file ... I am totally working in js file then how can I put php tags inside my js file ??? Its totally a bad idea as well ... I am using WordPress and I Also know wp_localize_script() /// that's also not working in my case .. as it only sends data once to js file while If I add my module again it will send data only of second ... so its not that case as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your PHP code you can use any variable which increments value after each code snippet gets inserted. Like shown below:

On top of the php code add:

```
 global $count;
 if $count == '' { $count = 0; }
```

It will just create a variable of global scope and if its empty it will set it to 0. Perfect, now just use this variable in your html class like shown below:

```
<div class="module-front-end-<?php echo $count;?>">HTML DATA GOES HERE </div> <?php $count++; ?>
```

Now in first insertion it will generate `module-front-end-0` and in second insertion it will become `module-front-end-1` and so on with each insertion of module.

Now just add another class, like get-data and your code will become like shown below:

```
<div class="get-data module-front-end-<?php echo $count;?>">HTML DATA GOES HERE </div>
```

So, your html part done now move to JS part, Inside your JS file just add code like shown below:

```
var count = 0;
$(".get-data").each(function(){
    $('module-front-end-'+count+).append('<p>this is my data</p>');
    count = count + 1;
}):
```

This way it will do the work for you. 
Note: `.append('<p>this is my data</p>');` is just for example purposes to show that how can you go inside your every dynamic class. You can do what ever you want to do with your code there.

Comment: Yes I go the idea and it looks great, let me apply and check hope this can save my day now ... :)